# foundation responsive sticky menu typo3 hmenu

Tags: templates, menu, typo3, zurb-foundation, fluid

I am new to Typo3, Fluid and Typoscript and I hope someone can help me...

I am using a responsive sticky menu for a Typo3-project which can bei found here:

https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/responsive-sticky-menu.html

The source code of the menu is:

```
<div data-sticky-container>
  <div data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;">

    <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
      <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="example-menu"></button>
      <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
    </div>

    <div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
      <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal dropdown menu" data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown">
        <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">One</a>
          <ul class="menu vertical nested">
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

This is the source code of the part inside my template containing the fluid variable for the menu "menuPrimary":

```
<div data-sticky-container>
            <div data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;">

                <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
                    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="example-menu"></button>
                    <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
                </div>

                <div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
                    <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal dropdown menu" data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown">
                      <li class="menu-text">{labelSiteTitle -> f:format.raw()}</li>
                      {menuPrimary -> f:format.raw()}
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to create a menu containing two levels: this is a sample structure of the pages an sub pages. This is my TypoScript:

> 10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
>   10 {
>       file = fileadmin/templates/vorlage.html
>
> ```
> variables {  
>
>   labelSiteTitle = TEXT  
>   labelSiteTitle.value = Testseite  
>
>   menuPrimary = HMENU  
>   menuPrimary {  
>     special = directory  
>     special.value = 3  
>
>     1 = TMENU  
>     1 {  
>       NO = 1  
>       NO {  
>         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  
>       }  
>
>     }  
>
>     2 = TMENU  
>     2 {  
>       NO = 1  
>       NO {  
>         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  
>       }  
>     }  
>
>   }  
>
>   contentMain < styles.content.get
>
> }
> ```

So what am i doing wrong? I just want to have exactly the same menu like from the buidling block found on https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/responsive-sticky-menu.html.

This is my page structure inside Typo3:

```
root
-main navigation
 |--Homepage
 |--News
 |--Private
 |--About Us
    |---Team
    |---blabla
    |---...
```

Thank you very much for your help!

This is my output in frontend:

```
<div data-sticky-container>
            <div data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;">

                <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
                    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="example-menu"></button>
                    <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
                </div>

                <div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
                    <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal dropdown menu" data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown">
                      <li class="menu-text">Testseite</li>
                      <li><a href="index.php?id=5">Homepage</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index.php?id=6">News</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index.php?id=7">Private</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index.php?id=8">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my output after clicking on "About Us":

```
<div data-sticky-container>
            <div data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;">

                <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
                    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="example-menu"></button>
                    <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
                </div>

                <div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
                    <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal dropdown menu" data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown">
                      <li class="menu-text">Testseite</li>
                      <li><a href="index.php?id=5">Homepage</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index.php?id=6">News</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index.php?id=7">Private</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index.php?id=8">About Us</a>
                          <li><a href="index.php?id=9">Team</a></li>
                          <li><a href="index.php?id=10">blabla</a></li>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What output do you get in frontend?

Comment: Hello David,
thank you very much in advance,
I appended the output to at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second level is not wrapped with `<ul class="menu vertical nested">|</ul>`.
I don't know yet if it's solving your issue but you should write it like this:

```
...

1 = TMENU  
1 {  
  expAll = 1
  NO = 1
  NO {
    wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  }
  IFSUB = 1
  IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="is-dropdown-submenu-parent opens-right">|</li>
}
2 = TMENU  
2 {  
  wrap = <ul class="menu vertical nested">|</ul>
  NO = 1  
  NO {  
    wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  
  }  
}  
....
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly the solution of my problem!

Comment: Thank you very much, that nearly solves my problem.
If "About Us" is active, everything is fine. The "Down Arrow" is being displayed.
But however, if I am on the homepage for example, the Menu Link "About Us" has no "Down Arrow". So there must be still missing something like IFSUB inside the first level...

Comment: That works almost perfect. The only thing that is still missing is that being on the homepage (level1) for example, the menu links to "Team" and "blabla" do not automatically expand when hovering over "About Us" like in the building block on foundation-site. Do you have any hint for that?
I think that the solution is that level2 menu points already have to be included inside the level1 menu on start but don`t know how to solve this

Comment: added `expAll = 1` on level 1, if needed you can do the same on level 2 too.

Comment: Edit: using expAll = 1 I can omit
IFSUB = 1
  IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="is-dropdown-submenu-parent opens-right">|</li>

Comment: Ok, that depends on CSS and JS ;-)